# Polyglossia and French hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

What am I doing wrong here?
Hyphenation seems to be missing.

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{xunicode}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}

\begin{document}

Couvert de sa cape blanche à doublure rouge sang,
marchant d’une démarche traînante de cavalier, tôt un matin du quatorze du mois
printanier de nisan, sous le portique couvert qui séparait les deux ailes

\end{document}
```

And that is how I render it:

```
xelatex 1.tex
```

[image]

Here is the `xelatex` output:

```
LaTeX2e <2021-11-15> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2022-01-21>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xltxtra/xltxtra.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifluatex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-xetex.def
(|extractbb --version))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/realscripts/realscripts.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/xelatex/xunicode/xunicode.sty
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/makecmds/makecmds.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)

LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'file/after/tracklang.sty' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'file/tracklang.sty/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/bidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/bidi/after' instead.


LaTeX hooks Warning: Generic hook 'package/after/luabidi' is deprecated.
(hooks)              Use hook 'package/luabidi/after' instead.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-latex.ldf))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/gloss-french.ldf)
(./phrases3.aux) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf/tex/latex/tipa/t3cmr.fd)
Overfull \hbox (125.16002pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 10--13
\TU/lmr/m/n/12 un matin du quatorze du mois printanier de nisan, sous le portiq
ue couvert
```

Comment: your example produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iM5Cj.png) in texlive 2023. show your log file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: added

Comment: @DavidCarlisle:You seem to be right... When I just copy paste the same text back from browser, it just works. What hidden symbols can it be?

Comment: if you use no break space rather than space it can't break the line. for example

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Sorry, I removed two lines from my example; put them back now; but they seem to be irrelevant anyway

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, you are right. It was nbsp indeed. Can please put your answer to the answer's section, so I could mark as the right one?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, I understand, that's why I corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the original source (but not the file as posted here) has nonbreaking space U+00A0 instead of spaces.

[image]